Using .git-prompt.sh to show Git branch name disappears after activating Python venv
I have a .bashrc like:
# Color mappings
grey='\[\033[1;30m\]'
red='\[\033[0;31m\]'
RED='\[\033[1;31m\]'
green='\[\033[0;32m\]'
GREEN='\[\033[1;32m\]'
yellow='\[\033[0;33m\]'
YELLOW='\[\033[1;33m\]'
purple='\[\033[0;35m\]'
PURPLE='\[\033[1;35m\]'
white='\[\033[0;37m\]'
WHITE='\[\033[1;37m\]'
blue='\[\033[0;34m\]'
BLUE='\[\033[1;34m\]'
cyan='\[\033[0;36m\]'
CYAN='\[\033[1;36m\]'
NC='\[\033[0m\]'

# Source git prompt for git info in prompt
source ~/.git-prompt.sh

# Prompt style
# \t is 24h time
# \w is working directory
# \s is shell name
PS1="$PURPLE\t\n$CYAN\w\n$RED$(__git_ps1 "(%s) ")$white\s $GREEN> "

# Add newline after each command
PROMPT_COMMAND="echo"

But its finnicky when I cd into a git directory or if I activate a Python venv using source ./venv/Scripts/activate. Either the branch or the venv disappears.
Goal state would be to have my PS1 show like the below when I am in a git repo/have a python venv active without any interference amongst the two being present at the same time as well as maintaining proper state when cding around my file system.
Ideal PS1:
PS1="$PYTHON_VIRTUAL_ENV$PURPLE\t\n$CYAN\w\n$RED$(__git_ps1 "(%s) ")$white\s $GREEN> "
FYI: I am using bash via Msys on Windows

I seemed to have got it to work by doing:
PS1="${PURPLE}\t\n${CYAN}\w\n${RED}\$(__git_ps1 \"(%s) \")${white}\s ${GREEN}> ", but I honestly don't understand why I have to escape the $ as well as the double quotes that surround (%s). Doing one or the other gives me a syntax error.
